# Why passed value is nil in viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift3

I know this is simple question but I couldn't understand for hours what's the problem here.

```
enum TypeOfAlert {
    case success, error, warning, confirm
}

class MainAlertView: UIViewController {

    var mode: TypeOfAlert!

    var transitioner : CAVTransitioner    

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        self.transitioner = CAVTransitioner()
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        self.transitioningDelegate = self.transitioner

        setupAlertView()
    }

    private func setupAlertView() {
       print(mode) // result is nil
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    } 
}
```

I have this code to show alertdialog

I opening MainAlertView by pressing a button

```
let vc = IFOMainAlertView()
    vc.delegate = self
    vc.mode = TypeOfAlert.confirm
    self.present(vc,animated: true)
```

but when I am printing or debuging var mode is always nil. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have printed var mode before you set it

Comment: I didn't get it what you said

Comment: In init you call setupAlertMode, which print value of var 'mode', but value for 'mode' you set after init

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to debug at initialisation moment,

when you called

```
let vc = IFOMainAlertView()
```

the function init was called, before you called the rest:

```
vc.delegate = self
vc.mode = TypeOfAlert.confirm
```

either add a new constructor to your class that takes `mode` as an argument, or delay debugging the mode attribute to the `viewDidLoad` method